# Parsing text in columns

Tags: python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup

I have written a code to parse a part of my html, see code below. The end result i have saved as a html for example purposes in dropbox (https://www.dropbox.com/s/kbnal2pefih2ru4/test.html?dl=0).
But my question is how can i furter edit my code so i can print the strong parts (bold text) in one column and in the next column the normal text.

```
import textwrap
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

directory ='C:/Research syntheses - Meta analysis/SeekingAlpha/Tests/'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.html'):
        fname = os.path.join(directory,filename)
        with open(fname, 'r') as f:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(),'html.parser')
            participants = soup.find('div',class_='content_part hid', id='article_qanda')
        print(filename, participants)
```

So my endresult would look something like this in csv format: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hzfW.png)

[image]

Comment: Based on your html file- _<p><strong><span class="question">Scott Henry</span></strong></p>_ , you should target <strong> tags to filter out your column 1 and then the subsequent tag after <strong> tag for column 2

Comment: @atinjanki thank you, i am not so experienced in python, so how could i achieve this suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

We can use a pandas dataframe to make it in that table format you want. Can we assume that every other p will contain a strong? If so, this should work:

```py
strong = []
not_strong = []

all = soup.find_all('p')
for i in range(0,len(all),2):   # loop every other
    strong.append(all[i])
    strong.append(all[i+1])

d = {'column 1': strong, 'column 2': not_strong}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Then it should print in the format you want. If we cannot make this assumption we'd have to determine whether or not each p contains a strong then append that and the next p to the appropriate list.

Comment: no not Always, for instance in the beginning of the html example you can see there are double strongs after each other.